# Delete Worksheet from Excel doesn't appear to be working

Tags: excel, vb6

I am attempting to replace the last worksheet in an Excel spreadsheet using VB6. Since deleting the last worksheet isn't allowed, I have been trying to add a temporary worksheet, delete the one I don't want, replace the old one, then delete the temporary worksheet, like so:-

```
Set temporary_sheet = mwbkBook.Worksheets.Add
temporary_sheet.Name = "NameThatIsUnlikelyToExist"    ' Error Here.

For Each lSheet In mwbkBook.Worksheets
    Select Case lSheet.Name
        Case "SheetToReplace"
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            lSheet.Delete
    End Select
Next lSheet

Set mwshSheet = mwbkBook.Worksheets.Add
mwshSheet.Name = "SheetToReplace"
' Fill in mwshSheet

For Each lSheet In mwbkBook.Worksheets
    Select Case lSheet.Name
        Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "NameThatIsUnlikelyToExist"
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            lSheet.Delete
    End Select
Next lSheet
```

The first invokation of this code gives me a spreadsheet containing one worksheet, `"SheetToReplace"`, as I verify by displaying the spreadsheet.

The second invokation gives an error at the line indicated:-

```
Cannot rename a sheet to the same name as another sheet, a referenced object library or a workbook referenced by Visual Basic.
```

(Number 1004).

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this invisible worksheet, or a better way of achieving the desired result?

Comment: you logic seems to be ok. if you really need to keep only `SheetToReplace` after your last looping change `conditional statement` inside the last loop to opposing logic (instead of `Select Case` use `if...end if`: `If lSheet.Name <> "SheetToReplace" then .... End if`.

Comment: You say the sheet is hidden? You'll need to make it visible first then delete it.

Comment: @glh, That has certainly improved matters. The worksheet is now deleted, but only if you leave it for a short while; I guess there is some asynchronous work being done. If you'd like to write that as an answer, I'll tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the sheet is hidden? You'll need to make it visible first then delete it.

Try:

```
lSheet.Visible = TRUE
lSheet.Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

> Since deleting the last worksheet isn't allowed..

If you only want to delete the last sheet, you can do

```
mwbkBook.Sheets(mwbkBook.Sheets.Count).Delete
```